# Calling a function for each Worksheet in a Workbook VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm a beginner at VBA and can't seem to figure out how to call a function in all the Worksheets in a Workbook. Is there a way to call a function like this? I would like it to be in 2 separate Subs if possible. Thanks.

```
Sub Formuoli2()

Dim iLastRow As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet
    iLastRow = 5
    For i = 1 To iLastRow
        Range("A" & i) = "a" 'these are formulas
        Range("B" & i) = "b" 'these are formulas
        Range("C" & i) = "c" 'these are formulas
        Range("D" & i) = "d" 'these are formulas
        Range("E" & i) = "e" 'these are formulas
        Range("F" & i) = "f"
    Next i
End Sub

Sub Formuoli3()
Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        With ws
            Call Formuoli2
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add one line:

```
 .Select
 Call Formuoli2
```

Comment: Thank you! Do you have any idea what the "Method 'Select' of object 'Worksheet' failed means in this context?

Comment: Not sure why you would get that. Do you have hidden sheets?

Comment: No - I tried to expand this logic to another macro though. What are the important parts about Formuoli2 that allow you to do this?

Comment: in case of sheets, better use `.Activate` because you can select multiple sheets at one time but only 1 can be active ;)

Comment: You should probably start a new question and post your other code.

Comment: @Rob as said by other people: better pass the parameter and work directly with the sheet instead of activating/selecting... simply because this will result in errors sooner or later...

Comment: Rob: try @Rory solution ... and avoid .activating/selecting

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the worksheet directly as an argument to the second sub:

```
Sub Formuoli2(ws As Worksheet)

    Dim iLastRow              As Long
    Dim i                     As Long

    iLastRow = 5
    For i = 1 To iLastRow
        ws.Range("A" & i) = "a"    'these are formulas
        ws.Range("B" & i) = "b"    'these are formulas
        ws.Range("C" & i) = "c"    'these are formulas
        ws.Range("D" & i) = "d"    'these are formulas
        ws.Range("E" & i) = "e"    'these are formulas
        ws.Range("F" & i) = "f"
    Next i
End Sub

Sub Formuoli3()
    Dim ws                    As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        Call Formuoli2(ws)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: sorry, I was editing my answer while you posted yours. It's that "over tuning" that beats me!

Answer (score 0):

it's better to pass `ws` to `Formuoli2()` sub

```
Option Explicit

Sub Formuoli3()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        Formuoli2 ws
    Next
End Sub


Sub Formuoli2(ws As Worksheet)
    Dim iLastRow As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

    iLastRow = 5
    With ws
        For i = 1 To iLastRow
            .Range("A" & i).Resize(, 6) = Array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f") 'these are formulas
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! Just out of curiousity, why is it better?

Comment: FYI your `With` block isn't doing anything because your `Range` call is missing a `.` in front of it.

Comment: you should avoid Selecting/Activating sheets and/or cells and use full reference to ranges for mostly three reasons 1) it makes sure what cell of what sheet of what workbook you're actually acting on, while `Activate` or `Select` gives you an _instant_ active sheet that could be changed right after by some user's choice or subsequent code statements themselves (possibly without realizing it) 2) activating sheets is a time consuming work 3) activating sheets causes screen flickering

Comment: If doing it like this, just do directly a `ws.Range("A1:F" & iLastRow).Value = Array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f")` instead of looping... ;)

Comment: @Dirk Reichel: Actually I thought about it (and in the meanwhile Rory overcame me...), but since OP's code I assumed that those "formulas" would change from row to row. Should they be the same for all rows, than I'd do as per your suggestion.